# Power Shell List Directories that contain file type

Tags: powershell

Trying to get a list of directories that contain .123 files.  Just need the directory Name \ Path.  Have tried Get-ChildItem with many options

```
get-childitem -Directory -Recurse -Filter *.123 |Select-Object FullName
```

Would like to output to a CSV file.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should give you the output you want

`Get-childitem -Recurse -Filter *123 | select-object directory -Unique | Export-Csv -Path file.csv`

Notice that we are looking for files, so no `-directory` switch is needed, and then we can select the directory property of the file.

The `-unique` switch will prevent us getting the same directory multiple times if it contains more than one file with your filter option.

Comment: And add another pipe to the end to ` | Export-CSV -Path "C:\out.csv"`

Comment: `Group-Object Directory -NoElement` instead of select would have the benefit of also counting the files.